# Unresolved Host Broke sudo

Tags: permissions

We operate a multi-domain (vhost) virtual AWS instance, ubuntu 20.04. Login as root is disabled on the server.

An unknown system recently created a hostname file, with no matching entry made to the hosts file, so we began receiving unresolved host errors, preventing many applications (e.g. Apache) from loading but most importantly preventing sudo from working. That is we cannot edit any files other than what belongs to user ubuntu. So we cannot edit hosts, or remove hostname.

We do not have a snapshot that can be used as a viable restore

Are there any possible workarounds for this catch 22 we are caught in?
In summary is there any way to delete the hostname file or edit the hosts file when we cannot be root?

Comment: If you're asking whether there's any way for an unprivileged user to make changes to restricted files, the answer is "not without a very good hacker on the payroll". If this were not the case, then Ubuntu would be about as secure as a wet tissue 

Comment: Being unable to resolve the local system's host name is only a warning message from ```sudo```, and shouldn't prevent actual operation so there must be something else wrong. What exactly happens when you try something e.g. ```sudo whoami```?

Comment: sudo whoamil returns the same as other sudo commands
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-xx-xx-xxx: Temporary failure in name resolution
root
I understand the bizarre notion that we are trying to in essence hack the system but I am trying to explore solutions to the situation where hosts/hostname file is causing issues that need root access to fix while at the same time not allowing the use of sudo to become root